# PHP - mysql insert syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble submitting some data to MySQL via php, i get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'signal values('123', 'NOW()', 'abc')' at line 1

this is the php code:

```
<?php
$uid = $_POST['selected_user'];
$signal_type = $_POST['signal_type'];
$query_search = "insert into signal values('$signal_type', NOW(), '$uid')";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

this is the table:
[image]

Comment: `signal` is a reserved word.

Comment: surround the puppy with back ticks (upper left of keyboard). Concern yourself with the ones with an (R) ---> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Higher Power be praised, Riz is awake.

Comment: @Drew It is 4 o' clock in the morning, of course I'm awake :)

Comment: You might want to verify your POST variables before using them, not to mention that your code is prone to SQL injection.  Additionally, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  You should use `mysqli_*` or PDO functions instead.  If you use the newer functions and use prepared statements and bound variables, your code will be much safer.